Hugging Face Prompt Injection Identifier
packages versions

langchain==0.1.14
langchain-community==0.0.31
langchain-core==0.1.38
langchain-experimental==0.0.56
pydantic==1.10.14

I am attempting to utilize prompt injection identification following the guidelines outlined in the tutorial linked here.
Here's the code snippet I'm using to load the injection identifier:
from optimum.onnxruntime import ORTModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, pipeline

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("ProtectAI/deberta-v3-base-prompt-injection", 
                                           subfolder="onnx")
tokenizer.model_input_names = ["input_ids", "attention_mask"]
model = ORTModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("ProtectAI/deberta-v3-base- 
                                                          prompt-injection", 
                                                          export=False, 
                                                          subfolder="onnx",
                                                       file_name="model_optimized.onnx"
                                                         )

classifier = pipeline(
                     task="text-classification",
                     model=model,
                     tokenizer=tokenizer,
                     truncation=True,
                     max_length=512,
                    )

from langchain_experimental.prompt_injection_identifier import (
                                                        HuggingFaceInjectionIdentifier,
                                                        )

injection_identifier = HuggingFaceInjectionIdentifier(
                                                     model=classifier,
                                                    )

However, I encounter the following error:
ERROR: pydantic.errors.ConfigError: field "model" not yet prepared so type is still a 
ForwardRef, you might need to call 
HuggingFaceInjectionIdentifier.update_forward_refs().
CONTEXT: Traceback (most recent call last):


update 2024-05-22: I've merged a fix to Langchain here

I encountered the same error, here is my patch. The same issue was raised at https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/19995.
First, your error message encourages you to call HuggingFaceInjectionIdentifier.update_forward_refs(). However, if you do this, you will encounter another error.
I patch this by creating a new version of the HuggingFaceInjectionClassifier that ignores typing errors:
from langchain_experimental.prompt_injection_identifier import (
    HuggingFaceInjectionIdentifier,
)
from typing import Union, Any

class PatchedHuggingFaceInjectionIdentifier(HuggingFaceInjectionIdentifier):
    def __init__(__pydantic_self__, **data: Any) -> None:
        try:
            super(PatchedHuggingFaceInjectionIdentifier, __pydantic_self__).__init__(**data)
        except ValidationError as pve:
            print(f'This is a warning. __init__ failed to validate:\n {json.dumps(data, indent=4)}\n')
            print(f'This is the original exception:\n{pve.json()}')


    @classmethod
    def parse_obj(cls: Any, obj: Any) -> 'Model':
        try:
            return super(PatchedHuggingFaceInjectionIdentifier, cls).parse_obj(obj)
        except ValidationError as pve:
            print(f'This is a warning. parse_obj failed to validate:\n {json.dumps(obj, indent=4)}')
            print(f'This is the original exception:\n{pve.json()}')
            return None

    @classmethod
    def parse_raw(cls: Any, b: Any, *, content_type: str = None, encoding: str = 'utf8',
                  proto: Any = None, allow_pickle: bool = False, ) -> 'Model':
        try:
            return super(PatchedHuggingFaceInjectionIdentifier, cls).parse_raw(b=b, content_type=content_type, encoding=encoding,
                                                              proto=proto, allow_pickle=allow_pickle)
        except ValidationError as pve:
            print(f'This is a warning. parse_raw failed to validate:\n {b}')
            print(f'This is the original exception:\n{pve.json()}')
            return None


from langchain_experimental.prompt_injection_identifier import hugging_face_identifier.
i m getting  this error: TypeError: cannot pickle 'classmethod' object

You should give an answer, ‘I have this error’ is not an answer

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
